# BaseClass inheritance from a separate file

Tags: python, class, inheritance, module, code-organization

I am automating an environment that consists of multiple independent applications. At some point I have decided that it will make the most sense to define each application as a class and save it as a separate file.

**What I have at the moment:**

A directory with `*py` files where each file defines a single class for a single application. So, for example, I have application `App1`. It is saved in `App1.py` file and looks something like this:

```
class App1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.link = config.App1_link
        self.retry = config.App1_retry
    def access(self):
        pass
    def logOut(self):
        pass
```

So each class defines all operations App1 can perform, like start\login to the application, perform operation, log out from the application, etc..

Then, in a separate file I create application objects and call object's methods one by one to create a multiple-steps scenario.

**What I want to achieve**

It all works fine but there is a place for improvement. Many of the class methods are more or less similar (for example methods like login\logout to\from the application) and clearly could be defined in some kind of base class I can then inherit from. However, since I have all the applications defined in separate files (which seems the logical solution at the moment), I don't know where to define such base class and how to inherit from it. I had 2 options in mind but I'm not sure which one (if any) will be the proper way to do it.

1. Define a base class in a separate file and then import it into each one of the application classes. Not sure if that's even makes sense.
2. Create one very long file with all the applications classes and include the base class in the same file. **Note**: such file will be really huge and hard to maintain since each application has its own methods and some of them a fairly big files by themselves.

So are these the only options I have and if they are, which one of them makes more sense?

Comment: Why doesn't option 1 make sense? That's a great option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your input. I just wasn't sure if that's considered to be a good approach. I mean importing class from a separate file. Actually I have already tried that but probably made some mistakes and it didn't work properly. But I guess that the actual implementation is a separate question. Thanks again.

Comment: The majority of the Python standard library wouldn't be possible if it didn't work like that. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters So I guess it answers my question then :) If you wish to post it as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what importing is *for*. Define your base class in a separate module, and import it wherever you need it. Option 1 makes excellent sense.

Note that Python's [module naming convention](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) is to use lowercase names; that way you can distinguish between the class and the module much easier. I'd rename `App1.py` to `app1.py`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I assume that when you say module, you refer to the actual file?

Comment: Yes, the filename forms the module name.